# Swap div contents onclick with AJAX

Tags: html, ajax

I simply want to swap contents of two divs when pressing a button using AJAX.

I made a simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uz1vmy17/) just to demonstrate what I mean.
So I want to swap A with B and B with A at the same time (while the red and green box stay at the same place) using onclick.

```css
.box1 {
  border: 2px solid green ;
}

.box2 {
  border: 2px solid red ;
}
```

```html
<div id="rank1" class="box1">
  B
</div>
    
<div id="rank2" class="box2">
  A
</div>
```

Comment: where you want to click ?

Comment: Why do you want to use `ajax` for swaping?

Answer (score 0):

use jquery to do this

include jquery js in html head tag

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
```

and following script to change the content

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sbutton').click(function() {
        var div1_value = $( "#rank1" ).html();
        var div2_value = $( "#rank2" ).html();
        $( "#rank1" ).html(div2_value);
        $( "#rank2" ).html(div1_value)
    });
  });
</script>
```

add a button in your html body

```
<input type="button" id="sbutton" value="Change"/>
```